# Possible bug with <select><option> value modification and Back button on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, button, back

Chrome Version (type about:Version 28.0.1491.0 canary and 26.0.1410.65 Google Chrome):
Operating System (Mac OS X Mountain Lion):
The problem only occurs with Chrome Canary and regular Google Chrome. 
There is no issue with Firefox, Safari nor IE9 (Windows tested) latest versions.

The code below changes all the stateBill values to be the same as the text values.

Then submit it to another page and  click Back button of browser page. The selected option is NOT visible (ie it shows blank) on the drop down, even though the html source still shows it selected.

If I don't execute the jquery function and submit and click Back on browser, the selected option text appears in the dropdown list correctly.

Maybe its jquery on chrome or maybe its javascript  on Chrome issue.

Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"
    >
<html>
</head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form target="_self" action="http://google.com">
    Click Submit. When it goes to google, Click Back button of browser.<br/>
    Will see that drop down is empty!
    <!-- Abbreviated states list -->
    <select name="stateBill" class="required" id="stateBill">
        <option value="">- Select -</option>
        <option value="1">Alabama</option>
        <option value="2">Alaska</option>
        <option value="3" >American Samoa</option>
        <option value="4" selected="selected">Arizona</option>
        <option value="5">Arkansas</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
<form>
</body>
<script>
$(function(){
    // Change all state values to be the same as the state text.
    var text;
    $("#stateBill option:gt(0)").each(function(i,j){
        text=$(j).text();
        $(j).val(text);
    }); 
})
</script>
<html>
```

Comment: Are you looking for a workaround, an explanation, or what?

Comment: I found an simple workaround by creating a hidden <input> text and just before a submit or change set it to the selected value. Is there another suggestion? I guess I was wondering if this is a bug or I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: I stumbled across the same problem, and after hours of headbanging against my own code, I came to the same conclusions. The autocomplete=off instantly fixed it.

Comment: This just hit me now. 6 years after. Do we know the root of it?

Comment: No. Just use one of the suggested workarounds and move on :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an simple workaround by creating a hidden  text and just before a submit or change set it to the selected value.

Answer (score 25):

I was having the same issue, and came across this issue while searching Google. For anyone else stumbling across this: I fixed the issue by setting 'autocomplete="off"' on the form. Of course, this may not be desirable for all situations.

I'm running Chrome 30.0.1599.101 on OSX 10.9. The web site is built using the Wicket framework (which uses jQuery for AJAX).

Comment: How did you find it? It's a pure black magic. We should be officially designated as sorcerers.

Comment: Genius. I'd already spent hours... but you saved me hours MORE. THANK YOU.

Comment: Am still getting this issue on Chrome 47 with Wicket. Wrapped my select in a form and added autocomplete=off and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Oh, my word. I was starting to think it was impossible and was prepared to re-do the entire page (writing asp.net `DropDownLists` to the page from the code behind) and use an `UpdatePanel`. This issue was a huge deciding factor. I set `AutoComplete="Off"` and it worked. Yeah, that saved me a ton of hours of work.

Comment: @chris-snyder - how did you find the solution?

Comment: @SpaceBeers— It's been a while, so I don't remember the specifics. But I'm sure it was my usual combination of domain knowledge (at least an awareness that the 'autocomplete' attribute is a thing), web searches, experimentation, and dumb luck.

Answer (score 0):

Simple jQuery workaround.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("select").each(function () {
        $(this).val($(this).find('option[selected]').val());
    });
})
```